# JavaScript class has setter that returns this. How do I document this in JsDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

Sample code:

```
var myObject = (function() {
    var M;

    M = function() {
    }

    M.prototype = {
        constructor: M,
        setSomeProperty = function(someValue) {
            // Do Stuff
            return this; // For chaining purposes
        }
    }

    return M
}());
```

What would the `@returns` tag look like when documenting the `setSomeProperty` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would look like this:

```
@returns {M} <code>this</code>
```

`{M}` indicates the class of what is returned, and `<code>this</code>` clearly indicates what is returned. If you use the markdown plugin:

```
@returns {M} `this`
```

A more verbose version would be:

```
@returns {M} The instance on which this method was called.
```

Or you could omit the class information and let the reader infer it.

Comment: I much prefer the last version. The idea of documentation is to document the code, not simply repeat it verbatim.

Comment: Just yesterday I've come across a library where having `@returns <code>this</code>` would have been immediately comprehensible and immensely useful. Just reading the code (which is often the pat response given in these cases) would not have made it clear because the top level method was doing `return this.other_method(...)`, which was doing `return this.yet_another(...)`, etc. Having `@returns <code>this</code>` in the documentation (which I was reading anyway) would have made it immediately clear.

Comment: As would a descriptive documentation comment that makes sense within automatically generated documentation, far from the code itself.